# Why can the Bellman-Ford algorithm be used without the full network view?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I have been reading up some applications of the Bellman-Ford algorithm and have come across this particular [thread](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34829/how-does-the-bellman-ford-algorithm-apply-to-real-networks). From what I can understand from it, it suggests that the Bellman-Ford algorithm does not need the full network view in order to operate properly (find the shortest path). Why is this? 
Secondly, I want to ask what exactly does "distributed" Bellman Ford mean? Specifically, how would one go about splitting a massive network so that we can use said "distributed" Bellman Ford.

Please correct me if I happen to be interpreting any of this incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The thread that you mentioned in the question discussed the usage of the Bellman-Ford algorithm to find the best routing path to send data packets between routers. In the beginning, each router starts with a vector of distances to all directly attached networks. Then, each router broadcast its current distance vector to all the neighboring routers. Each of the neighboring routers then will update the local copy of their distance vector and broadcast it again to its neighbors. In this way, each of the source routers of the network ultimately updates their own distance vector w.r.t. the other destination routers. Now you can imagine, all the routers ultimately calculate the shortest routing path (sourced from it) without knowing the complete network.

Recommended reading:

1. [Illustration of Distributed Bellman-Ford Algorithm](https://www.lewuathe.com/illustration-of-distributed-bellman-ford-algorithm.html)